# Android Gradle issues minify enable true

Tags: android

**Please help. In android when we minify enable true in gradle  after storing data in shared preference then app is kill(destroy) shared preference data not get ?**

Comment: Your question is not very clear but assuming that your are concerned about the data in `SharedPreferences` being affected by `minifyEnabled` settings in build.gradle, the answer is no `minifyEnabled` will not have any affect on the data in `SharedPreferences`

Comment: Post the stack trace.